# Integrating SAGA 7.8.1 into QGIS 3.16 (OS Windows 10)

Tags: qgis, saga, integration

I want to calculate the PV potential of roofing using QGIS, similar to this post:
[How to calculate total PV potential of a roof using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263087/how-to-calculate-total-pv-potential-of-a-roof-using-qgis).

However, my SAGA version in QGIS does not show me the **Potential Incoming Solar Radiation** algorithm.

I have downloaded a standalone SAGA version 7.8.1.

Can I integrate the latest/ update the current SAGA version that is used by my QGIS?

The OS I am using is Windows 10.

I am completely new to SAGA in QGIS and have no previous experience in using it.

Comment: It's possible in my Windows10. Which OS are you on?

Comment: I am also on Windows 10

Comment: Aah, I double checked, but the particular tool (Potential Incoming Solar Radiation) is not included in SAGA 7.8.1 in QGIS... Not sure you are still interested in.

Comment: I can see and select the tool in the SAGA standalone (v 7.8.1). 

The SAGA version my QGIS is using is an older, 2.2 version.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. What I meant was that the way to incorporate SAGA 7.8.1 to QGIS 3.16 I thought to suggest, does not include the tool you need.

Comment: Ah, ok. That's too bad because I will need to use that tool for the analysis I want to do. 

I would use the standalone SAGA version but cannot export my DOM Rasterlayer as it is a WMS layer and doesnt let me export it completely.

Comment: With the latest SAGA 7.8.2 (released on 26-Nov-2020), Potential Incoming Solar Radiation has become available in QGIS 3.16. Are you still interested in this? (I saw your post in SAGA Forum and you have been working with SAGA 7.8.2 standalone. Working directly in SAGA GUI is more efficient than doing computation through QGIS interface.)

Comment: Yes, absolutely! 

I would love to get some instructions on how to integrate it!

Answer (score 4):

[SAGA 7.8](https://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/SAGA%20-%207/) comes with **saga4qgis** and it provides support for SAGA Algorithms through QGIS Processing Toolbox.

This is a short instruction to install **saga4qgis** into QGIS 3.16, on Windows10 environment.

(1) Download latest SAGA

Visit SAGA in SorceForge.net, and download the latest zipped version of SAGA (i.e. saga-7.8.2_x64.zip).

[image]

(2) Unzip downloaded SAGA and search for **saga4qgis.zip** file.

[image]

(3) Unzip **saga4qgis.zip**

[image]

You will find two files and a folder.

- `readme.txt`: This is the instruction (see below).
- `SagaNameDecorator.py`
- `description` (folder with lots of description files)

Open `readme.txt` - it is short and sweet

```
Replace the SAGA binaries in:
> C:\Program Files\QGIS X.Y\apps\saga(-ltr)

Adjust the interface in:
> C:\Program Files\QGIS X.Y\apps\qgis(-ltr)\python\plugins\processing\algs\saga(-ltr)

Adjust version in file:
> SagaAlgorithmProvider.py
>> REQUIRED_VERSION = '7.7.'
```

(4) Folow the instruction as written in `readme.txt`.

That's it - below is my note but it has no additional information.

1. Open up `[aa] C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\apps\saga-ltr folder` and delete all files inside it.
2. Copy all files of unzipped `saga-7.8.2_x64.zip` to the above folder `[aa]`.
3. Open up `[bb] C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.16\ apps\ qgis\ python\ plugins\ processing\ algs\ saga` and search for **SagaNameDecorator.py** file. Replace this file by new `SagaNameDecorator.py` (which is in `saga4qgis.zip`).
4. In the same `[bb]` folder, find **SagaAlgorithmProvide.py** and open it by a text editor (e.g. Notepad++). Change `REQUIRED_VERSION = '2.3.'` to `REQUIRED_VERSION = '7.7.'`.
5. You will find **description** folder in the same `[bb]` folder. Delete all files in this `[bb]\description` folder, and copy all description files in `saga4qgis\description` into this.
6. Start QGIS 3.16 and examine QGIS Processing Toolbox.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kazuhito!

I had actually seen the SAGA4gis folder and also read the readme.txt. However, the instructions there were not clear enough to follow (I cannot clean out my ltr files somehow). 

Your instructions make things much more clear and I will try again. Thank you!