# Accessing SAGA algorithms (majority filter in particular) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, saga

I'm using QGIS 3.18.1 and have downloaded SAGA 7.8.2 (following [Integrating SAGA 7.8.1 into QGIS 3.16 (OS Windows 10)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380164/integrating-saga-7-8-1-into-qgis-3-16-os-windows-10)).

However, the majority filter option remains greyed out. I have tried installing the SAGA nextgen provider plugin, but that also appears to have no effect.

What can I do to make the tool available?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to double-click the tool and start using it? Although it looks greyed out, but it seems it works.