# Calculate PV rooftop potentials in Berlin QGIS 3.16. (OS Windows 10)

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, remote-sensing, saga

I want to analyse PV potentials of roofing in QGIS (v. 3.16).

I am experienced in vector data analysis but have barely worked with raster data sets. I therefore have no experience and am asking for assistance with the task.

I have access to the digital surface model of Berlin (as WMS layer) through the following link:

https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wms/senstadt/k_dom

I have read previous posts about similar analysis like:

[Calculating total PV potential of roof using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/263087/how-to-calculate-total-pv-potential-of-a-roof-using-qgis)

and am wondering if someone could guide me through a similar analysis.

The SAGA toolbox that I can open in QGIS does not offer the **Potential Incoming Solar Radiation** algorithm.

I have further installed a SAGA standalone (version 7.8.1) that offers the toolkit.

Is there another way to calculate Potential Solar Radiation?

Side note: I have installed the following programs on my computer (OS Windows 10):

- QGIS (3.16.1.) standalone
- SAGA (3.8.1.) standalone
- WinGRASS (7.8.4) standalone
- Python (3.8.6)

Comment: Please read up one what a WMS layer is, how it works, and what its limitations are. Then get back to the Senat-website and check for data downloads.

Comment: I did manage to export the WMS file now. The mistake was that I did not select an expansion when exporting it.

Comment: A WMS is "serving georeferenced map images over the Internet", see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Map_Service 
To be able to process the raster data, you should try to find a WCS that provides the data you need, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Coverage_Service